# Reindex stuck on processing and says 'Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.'

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex, index

The index Catalog URL Rewrites is stuck on processing.

When clicking on Reindex Data it gives the error 'Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.'

Other threads suggested deleting the files in the var/locks folder but for me the locks folder doesn't even exist.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

if you have ssh then login in putty and then go to root folder of
magento and run this command

`php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url`